# SQL Parameter Length VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a stored procedure that I use to run a query for information about client balances over time. It has the following syntax:

```
exec Client_Balance_SP @ClientList, @recentDate, @dateList
```

where @ClientList is a comma-delimited list of client names, i.e. 'Mary Sue, John Doe, Jimmy John', @recentDate is a date like '2015-05-11 00:00:00', and @dateList is a list of dates like '2015-05-04 00:00:00, 2015-04-27 00:00:00, ...'

The issue I am having is when the length of @dateList exceeds 100 characters; I get a run-time error in Excel. Is there a way to get around this issue that would allow me to run just one query?

Thanks!

Jay

Comment: Are you are using ADODB.Command to execute the procedure? Is the **@dateList** parameter length is more than 100 chars?

Comment: As a workaround, how about removing the time ( 00:00:00) from your @dateList dates? That would save 9 characters per date - almost half.

Comment: Jon - I am using ADODB.Connection.Execute to execute the procedure. And yes, the @dateList parameter is more than 100 chars.

Comment: Hannover - Nice name XD and that helps reduce the number of queries, at least, but I may still have parameters with lengths >100 chars :(

Answer (score 1):

I would try to either split the query such that the length of `@dateList`s is always less than 100.

And I think that the more elegant solution is to use a table for the `@datelist`.
For example

```
exec Client_Balance_SP @ClientList, @recentDate, (Select dt from #tbl_date_list)
```

And than your vba macro could preload `#tbl_date_list` from a csv or excel before the stored-procedure, (and delete it at the end, if you want).

And you will always have at most 2 queries regardless of the amount of items in the `@dateList`

See [temp tables](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html), and [bulk insert](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html) to read csv into them

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, @dateList is not coming from another table, rather is coming from another module I wrote in VBA independent of the database I am querying, and I don't have write access to the database (the stored procedure was generated by another team). Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use temporary tables, if you have permission to connect to the database you should have the privilege to create and drop temp tables (according to this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c903a88b-1a5b-4ba7-ab3d-81156e0dec72/permission-regarding-creating-temp-tables-in-mssql-2005?forum=transactsql)